# getting location of GSM towers

Tags: c#, .net, gsm

is there any way to programatically identify the locations of near GSM towers and we can show them in a map ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use google maps API to query lat long based on BST ID (tower)

Example in C# :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

//---Based on code written by "Neil Young" (neil.young@freenet.de)
//---Source: http://maps.alphadex.de/datafiles/fct0e1b11782832f02.cs
namespace GoogleMaps
{
    class GMM
    {
        static byte[] PostData(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID, 
                               bool shortCID)
        {
            /* The shortCID parameter follows heuristic experiences:
             * Sometimes UMTS CIDs are build up from the original GSM CID (lower 4 hex digits)
             * and the RNC-ID left shifted into the upper 4 digits.
             */
            byte[] pd = new byte[] {
                0x00, 0x0e,
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                0x00, 0x00,
                0x00, 0x00,
                0x00, 0x00,

                0x1b, 
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x11
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x15
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x19
                0x00, 0x00,
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x1f
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x23
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x27
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x2b
                0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
            };

            bool isUMTSCell = ((Int64)CID > 65535);

            if (isUMTSCell)
                Console.WriteLine("UMTS CID. {0}", shortCID ? 
                    "Using short CID to resolve." : "");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("GSM CID given.");

            if (shortCID)
                CID &= 0xFFFF;      /* Attempt to resolve the cell using the 
                                    GSM CID part */

            if ((Int64)CID > 65536) /* GSM: 4 hex digits, UTMS: 6 hex 
                                    digits */
                pd[0x1c] = 5;
            else
                pd[0x1c] = 3;

            pd[0x11] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x12] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x13] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x14] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

            pd[0x15] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x16] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x17] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x18] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

            pd[0x27] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x28] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x29] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x2a] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

            pd[0x2b] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x2c] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x2d] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x2e] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

            pd[0x1f] = (byte)((CID >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x20] = (byte)((CID >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x21] = (byte)((CID >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x22] = (byte)((CID >> 0) & 0xFF);

            pd[0x23] = (byte)((LAC >> 24) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x24] = (byte)((LAC >> 16) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x25] = (byte)((LAC >> 8) & 0xFF);
            pd[0x26] = (byte)((LAC >> 0) & 0xFF);

            return pd;
        }

        static public string GetLatLng(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 4)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            string shortCID = "";   /* Default, no change at all */
            if (args.Length == 5)
                shortCID = args[4].ToLower();
            try
            {
                String url = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                    new Uri(url));
                req.Method = "POST";

                int MCC = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
                int MNC = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
                int LAC = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
                int CID = Convert.ToInt32(args[3]);
                byte[] pd = PostData(MCC, MNC, LAC, CID, 
                    shortCID == "shortcid");

                req.ContentLength = pd.Length;
                req.ContentType = "application/binary";
                Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                outputStream.Write(pd, 0, pd.Length);
                outputStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                byte[] ps = new byte[res.ContentLength];
                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                while (totalBytesRead < ps.Length)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += res.GetResponseStream().Read(
                        ps, totalBytesRead, ps.Length - totalBytesRead);
                }

                if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    short opcode1 = (short)(ps[0] << 8 | ps[1]);
                    byte opcode2 = ps[2];
                    int ret_code = (int)((ps[3] << 24) | (ps[4] << 16) |
                                   (ps[5] << 8) | (ps[6]));
                    if (ret_code == 0)
                    {
                        double lat = ((double)((ps[7] << 24) | (ps[8] << 16) 
                                     | (ps[9] << 8) | (ps[10]))) / 1000000;
                        double lon = ((double)((ps[11] << 24) | (ps[12] << 
                                     16) | (ps[13] << 8) | (ps[14]))) / 
                                     1000000;
                        return lat + "|" + lon;
                    }
                    else
                        return string.Empty;
                }
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, but i can't understand this, can you help me to understand this, any links to  read regarding this?

Comment: This code sends BTS ID to google maps for getting location of GSM towers. Related article : http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/cell-phone-my-location-google-mobile-maps/